# Android onOrientationChange triggers before orientation completes (too early)

Tags: javascript, android, webkit, prototypejs

I need to read the pixel width of a DIV whenever the user rotates his phone. On iOS the following code will print out the DIV's width **after** the orientation completes. However, on Android the code will print out the DIV's width **before** the orientation starts.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="foo" style="width: 80%">foo</div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
window.onorientationchange = function() {
    alert($('foo').getWidth());
}
```

For example, the user starts in  portrait mode. He rotates to landscape mode. On Android, the code will print out the older narrower width, while iOS will print out the new wider width.

How do I make Android behave like iOS? The *after* width is important to me in my web application. The *before* width is useless to me.

Comment: Edit: The body width from `$$('body').first().getWidth()` is also out of date on Android.

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty solution would be to use a timer. you can continue development until a more suitable solution comes up.

edit: just recognized that on android the onorientationchange event is fired before resize event, this is diffrent from ipads behaviour. check the resize event on android phones, does this provide the right width?